# CSS background-repeat: no-repeat; still repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have...

```
    html, body {
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

As my CSS and in my HTML I have

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Wut</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page">
    </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var imgCount = 3;
        var dir = 'img/';
        var randomCount = Math.round(Math.random() * (imgCount - 1)) + 1;
        var images = new Array();
            images[1] = "1.png",
            images[2] = "2.png",
            images[3] = "3.png",
         document.body.style.background = "url(" + dir + images[randomCount] + ")";
    </script>
</body>
```

For some reason the background which is randomly selected by the JS scrolls and i don't want/need it to. Also as a side note: I managed to make it stop scrolling at one point but when i added background-color, half of the background image was covered up and you couldn't see the background image itself.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5):

The reason why it happens is because `background` is a composite property which includes `background-color`, `background-image`, `background-repeat`, `background-position`, `background-attachment`. It means that when you set `background` alone without specifying `background-repeat` you simply overwrite previously defined rule, it just falls back to default value which is `repeat`. To fix it you should explicitly provide it:

```
document.body.style.background = "url(" + dir + images[randomCount] + ") no-repeat";
```

or set `background-image` insted:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + dir + images[randomCount] + ")";
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the reason why the property get overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line

```
document.body.style.backgroundRepeat="no-repeat";
```

or another way existing line replace this one

```
document.body.style.background = "url(" + dir + images[randomCount] + ") no-repeat";
```

#### HTML

```
<html>
  <head> 
   <title>Wut</title>
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

<body>
    <div id="page">
    </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var imgCount = 3;
        var dir = 'img/';
        var randomCount = Math.round(Math.random() * (imgCount - 1)) + 1;
        var images = new Array();
            images[1] = "1.png",
            images[2] = "2.png",
            images[3] = "3.png",
         document.body.style.background = "url(" + dir + images[randomCount] + ")";
         document.body.style.backgroundRepeat="no-repeat";
    </script>
</body>
```

CSS no need to define

Answer (score 0):

Because you overwrite the whole background style with `document.body.style.background` including repeat property.

Change it with `document.body.style.backgroundImage`.

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CGn4Y/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's repeating, is that you're setting the **whole** background property. This overrides any specifics, such as `background-repeat`. Try this line:

```
document.body.style.background-image = "url(" + dir + images[randomCount] + ")"
```

instead of what you have.